# Why user.has_perm() is always returning false even after adding permission to user object by first instantiating it?

Tags: django

python manage.py shell code and all the outputs

```
>>> user1 = users[2]
>>> print(user1.username)
esther
>>> print(exam_permissions[3])
core | exam | Can view exam
>>> print(user1.has_perm(exam_permissions[3]))
False
>>> user1.user_permissions.add(exam_permissions[3])
>>> print(user1.has_perm(exam_permissions[3]))
False
>>>
```

Comment: What us `exam_permissions`?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between a user and assigned permissions is a many-to-many one.

Adding the permission like you do (only with `user1.user_permissions.add(exam_permissions[3])` does not save it in the database, thus, calling next `user1.has_perm(exam_permissions[3])` will always be `False`. You need to save the relationship or add it in an another way.

In the documentation you can find this explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

> Using add() with a many-to-many relationship, however, will not call any save() methods (the bulk argument doesn’t exist), but rather create the relationships using QuerySet.bulk_create(). If you need to execute some custom logic when a relationship is created, listen to the m2m_changed signal, which will trigger pre_add and post_add actions.